# How can add this type is a code to convert Wordpress shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to add this type code convert wordpress shortcode. Have any WordPress Plugin?

```
<ins class="bookingaff" data-aid="1316333" data-target_aid="" data-prod="rw" data-width="0" data-height="0" data-lang="en-US" data-show_rw_badge="1" data-show_rw_text="1" data-hid="56423">
    <!-- Anything inside will go away once widget is loaded. -->
    <a href="//www.booking.com?aid=">Booking.com</a>
</ins>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, sc, u) {
      var s = d.createElement(sc), p = d.getElementsByTagName(sc)[0];
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = u + '?v=' + (+new Date());
      p.parentNode.insertBefore(s,p);
      })(document, 'script', '//aff.bstatic.com/static/affiliate_base/js/flexiproduct.js');
</script>
```

Comment: Please try and ask again as I have no idea what you are asking...?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are asking to turn the snippet above into a shortcode. If that is what you're looking for you could use a plugin like [Snippy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/snippy) (disclaimer, I'm the author of the said plugin).

With Snippy you can create custom shortcodes without having to modify PHP files.

Create a new Snippy "bit" and copy the above HTML snippet to the value field, then add the "bit" to your very own [bookingaff] shortcode. If needed you can add placeholders to the HTML snippet for values you might want to change per page. There's more information to be found on the Snippy product page.